# ¿Como puedo consolidar información entre bases de datos de SQL Enterprise y Estandar?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una base de datos en la nube en SQL Enterprise y una base de datos Standar en servidor local la cual es afectada por los sistemas transaccionales, ambas base de datos tienen la misma estructura y quiero enviar la información del servidor local al servidor de la nube